# Reading profile script in non-interactive mode with AIX implementation of ksh

Tags: ssh, jenkins, ksh, aix

Please note that this is an AIX related question.

I have a jenkins server running on Redhat which is running a node via SSH on an AIX server.
The commands are run non-interactively using SSH to a user on the AIX machine who has ksh as its standard shell.

The problem is that this build needs a number of environment variables, and i can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried:
Jenkins allows me to set some environment variables for the session. So i tried:

```
ENV="$HOME/.profile"
```

I tried creating a .kshrc file containing

```
. .profile
```

But none of these approaches seems to make KSH run the .profile script.

The .profile script contains the environment setup for the user i need.

How do i get an AIX implementation of KSH to run my .profile script before executing commands?

Answer (score 1):

Most shells don't source their .profile files on non-interactive sessions. A simple solution is to source the .profile yourself as part of the command you are sending.

So instead of

```
yourcommand1; yourcommand2
```

you should send

```
. ~/.profile; yourcommand1; yourcommand2
```

over ssh

UPDATE after reading the comment about Jenkins controlling the ssh command

In the case your ssh command is performed by Jenkins you should have a look at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Slaves+plugin, especially the 'Login profile files' paragraph.

I'd say one of these solutions is best

1. Set all environment variables from Jenkins using the node's configure page. Install the [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin to do this.
2. Write a wrapper around the java command on the slave that sources your profile script and adjust the JavaPath (also on the node's configure page) to point to that wrapper.

Comment: The problem is that i don't control the commands being sent. jenkins does.

Comment: Isn't there a way to make the environment just source the profile script?

Comment: If you implement option 2, you should be able to source the profile script and after that launch java.

Comment: Sorry, i was unclear. The main question of how to make KSH actually read a profile script when in non-interactive mode remain unanswered. I already found the link you described in your answer prior to creating the case (Which i should have written in the case, pardon). The problem is we have 8 different Java versions defined and creating wrappers for them all is as impractical as it is ugly. If a wrapper script is the only way to fix this issue, then fine, so be it, but i would rather have KSH handle it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specifically tell Jenkins that you want to execute them in `ksh` shell.
By default, Jenkins runs as `sh <commands>`.

Add a shebang in your shell command as first line,

`#!/bin/ksh`

Comment: Doesn't the shell depend on the user on the recieving machine's /etc/passwd file?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of for setting environment variables that will apply for non-interactive shells on AIX is via /etc/environment. I believe this is the correct place, but it will of course then apply to all users and all shells.